# Why does the "relationship does not exist" error occur

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this model:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Superhero extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate ({ Image, Superpower }) {
      // define association here
      Superhero.hasMany(Image, { foreignKey: 'superheroId' });
      Superhero.hasMany(Superpower, { foreignKey: 'superheroId' });
    }
  }
  Superhero.init(
    {
      nickname: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        validate: { notEmpty: true, notNull: true, len: [1, 128] },
      },
      realName: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'real_name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
          len: [1, 128],
        },
      },
      originDescription: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'origin_description',
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
        },
      },
      superpowers: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
        },
      },
      catchPhrase: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'catch_phrase',
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
          len: [1, 255],
        },
      },
      images: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notNull: true,
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Superhero',
      underscored: true,
      tableName: 'superheroes',
    }
  );
  return Superhero;
};
```

I have such a superpower migration:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('superpowers', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      superheroId: {
        field: 'superhero_id',
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'superheroes',
          },
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
      },
      superpowerName: {
        field: 'superpower_name',
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('superpowers');
  },
};
```

When I try to run this command `npx sequelize db:migrate`, I get an error

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 16.14.2, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.21.0]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/db.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20220704175320-create-superpower: migrating =======

ERROR: relation "superheroes" does not exist
```

What could be the reason?
I have a hunch that the superpower table is trying to spawn before the superhero table.
Thus, when creating a table with a superpower, an attempt is made to link the "superheroId" field in the superpower table with the "id" field in the superhero table, which does not exist yet.

P.S. If necessary, the file structure looks something like this:

[image: file structure]

UPD. Migration with `superhero`:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Superhero extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate ({ Image, Superpower }) {
      // define association here
      Superhero.hasMany(Image, { foreignKey: 'superheroId' });
      Superhero.hasMany(Superpower, { foreignKey: 'superheroId' });
    }
  }
  Superhero.init(
    {
      nickname: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        validate: { notEmpty: true, notNull: true, len: [1, 128] },
      },
      realName: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'real_name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
          len: [1, 128],
        },
      },
      originDescription: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'origin_description',
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
        },
      },
      superpowers: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
        },
      },
      catchPhrase: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'catch_phrase',
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
          notNull: true,
          len: [1, 255],
        },
      },
      images: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
          notNull: true,
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Superhero',
      underscored: true,
      tableName: 'superheroes',
    }
  );
  return Superhero;
};
```

Comment: Show the migration with `superhero`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your syntax is off in the "references" object. The model property should be a string or a static model.

```
references: {
    model: 'superheroes'
    key: 'id'
}
```

[Documentation link](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/modelattributecolumnoptions#references)